# Animate windows with slide up/down like Linux Mint

Tags: window-manager

I would like my windows to slide up/down, like how Linux Mint animates. Is it possible? And if yes, then how?

Answer (score 1):

For all extra animations and transition. I recommend `CompizConfig`

Open the terminal and type
`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra`

Click `Effects` from the left pane and customize to your choice.